# Question tag problem

Tags: question-tags

What is the appropriate question tag for the following sentence?

> A man like you shouldn't do this , _________ ? ("should you" or "should he")

I think it should be "should you" after reading about question tags from my textbooks and conversations with my online friends. This question was in my English 2nd paper (Grammar) exam. My teacher said "should you" is incorrect and the answer is "should he" because "like" is a preposition in the sentence therefore "a man" is the subject.

Comment: Try 'A man like myself shouldn't do this, should I?'

Comment: What has the research you've already done told you? Why do you think one might be better than the other? Where have you looked already before asking here? Please edit your question to include these things.

Comment: [*A Town Like Alice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Town_Like_Alice) would be a nice place to live, wouldn't she?*

Comment: First of all , English isn't my first language . I think it should be "should you" after reading about question tags from my textbooks and conversations with my online friends . This question was in my English 2nd paper (Grammar) exam . my teacher said "should you" is incorrect and the answer is "should he" because "like" is a preposition in the sentence therefore "a man" is the subject .

Comment: Your teacher is right, except that "like" is an adjective here, not a preposition. "A man like you shouldn't do this, should he"?

Comment: @BillJ No, *like* is a preposition here meaning "similar to". *Like* may be an adjective meaning "having similar qualities" as in *I responded in **like manner**, but it's hard to see how the word could modify a pronoun.

Comment: Get a better teacher (or at least one who can write better tests).  Certainly *man* is the head of the noun phrase that's the subject of the sentence, but this has nothing to do with the lexical classification of *like*. If this sentence is the declaration of a general principle, then the topic is the indeterminate *man* (i.e., anyone like you), and the tag should reflect that as *should he*. If the topic is the person addressed, then tag *should you* shifts the meaning to the more pointed specific meaning of *you shouldn't do this*.

Comment: @deadrat. "Like" is one of just four adjectives that are transitive taking NP complements, in this case "you". Adjectival "like" means "resemble"; it occurs in predicatives such as "John is (very/just) like his father". And adjectival "like" can be modified by "very" and "just", cf "A man just like you shouldn't do this, should he"? Moreover, adjectival "like" is related to a predicand, in this case "man", whereas prep "like" is not. Prepositional "like" occurs as head of an adjunct as in "Like his father, John had been to Oxford University".

Comment: @BillJ Perhaps this is just semantics. Certainly the phrase *like you* is adjectival, but *like* here expresses a relationship, one characteristic of prepositions. Many of the relationships are spatial or temporal, but that's not necessary. It's true that *like* may be intensified or compared, but that's not exclusive to adjectives. Consider *I'm more in control than ever*. Predicands are required of adjectives, but it's a hallmark of prepositions that a predicand is optional for them. Perhaps I'm misinterpreting Huddleston and Pullum.